# When do Perl package variables fall out of scope?

Tags: perl, scope, perl-module

From my main program I require a file containing a package, and then call a subroutine from that package:

```
while($somecondition){
  require( 'people.pm' );
  my $result = PERSON::stuff($args);
}
```

The PERSON package has multiple subs and some 'our' variables declared:

```
package PERSON;
our $name;
our ...
sub stuff {
  ...
}
```

In my understanding of other more object oriented languages you would need to declare a new object instance, maybe with its own constructor/initialization functions to use "package" variables. That doesn't seem to be the case here with Perl.

I'm dealing with legacy code so I don't want to change much, I just want to understand when the package variables ($name) come into existence, and when are they returned to memory from the perspective of the main program.

Would putting a PERSON::stuff() call after the while loop have new package variables?
After calling a single function inside a package do the package variables live until the end of the program?

Comment: Re "*You would need to declare a new object instance*", It's 100% the same in Perl. If you just need one person, you can use global/package/class vars. But if you want more than one person, you'll need objects (or some other approach)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question mixes up some concepts so let's first address what appears to be the main issue:  If a package is `require`'d inside some scope, what of it outside of that scope?

In short, (dynamical global) symbols from the package are accessible everywhere in the unit in which it is `require`'d, via their fully qualified names.<sup>†</sup>

Let's try with an example

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use feature 'say';

TEST_SCOPE: {
    say "In scope, in ", __PACKAGE__;
    require TestPack;
    #hi();                  # "Undefined subroutine &main::hi called..."
    TestPack::hi();         # ok
    #say $global;           # $global ... who??
    say $TestPack::global;  # ok
    say "Leaving scope\n";
};

say "--- in ", __PACKAGE__;
TestPack::hi();             # ok
say $TestPack::global;      # ok
```

File `TestPack.pm`:

```
package TestPack;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

#use Exporter qw(import);  # This is normally done to export symbols
#our @EXPORT_OK = qw(hi);  # (unless the package is a class)

our $global = 7;

sub hi { say "hi from ", __PACKAGE__ }

1;
```

One needs to use fully qualified names for those symbols as they weren't imported.  If the package exports symbols and we import some<sup>‡</sup> then they go into the calling package's namespace so in the example above they'd be available in `main::`, so they can be accessed by any code in the interpreter by their exported names (`hi`, no need for `TestPack::hi`).  One cannot access lexical variables from that package (created with `my`, `our`, `state`)<sup>§</sup>.

This also works if instead of the mere block (named `TEST_SCOPE`) we introduce another package, and `require` our `TestPack` inside of it.

```
...    
package AnotherPack {
    require TestPack;
    ...
    1;
};
...
TestPack::hi();             # ok
...
```

(That `package` should be inside a `BEGIN` block really, what doesn't change the main point here.) Global symbols from `TestPack` are still accessible in `main::`, via their fully qualified names.  The exported names, which we import along with `require`, are then available as such *in this package*, but not in `main::`.

*Comments on the question*

- Package name (`PERSON`) and the filename for it (`person.pm`) *have to agree*.  For example, the namespace (==package) `Person` is defined in the file `Person.pm`
- This is about basics related to [require](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require)-ing a [package](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package); it has nothing to do with object-oriented notions. (Even though, a class *is* firstly a package. See [perlootut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut) and [perlobj](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj).)  Also see [*Packages* in perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod#Packages) and [our](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our).
- If you were to use a package that [bless](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless)-es, the returned object (instance) is (assigned to) a [lexical](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) variable.  As such, it doesn't exist outside of the scope.  The package itself, though, is visible just as shown above but in object-oriented work we don't want to poke at a package's insides, but rather use methods via objects.

  So yes, to work with that package outside of the scope in which it is `require`-ed you'd need to instantiate an object in that other scope as well.  That would still work much like the example above -- we *can* use the package name, outside of scope in which it was required, to instantiate an object (try!), even though I'd raise questions of such design (see next)
- This hints at a convoluted design though, bringing in packages inside scopes, at runtime (via `require`); what is the context? (And I hope it's not really in a `while` loop.)

---

<sup>†</sup>  Print out the main's symbol table, `%main::` (using `Data::Dumper` for example) and we find

```
"TestPack::" => *main::TestPack::
```

along with all other symbols from `TestPack` namespace.

---

<sup>‡</sup>  If a package exports symbols and we `require` the package then we can import by

```
require Pack::Name;
Pack::Name->import( qw(subname anothername ...) );
```

---

<sup>§</sup> Note that `our` creates a lexical which is an alias for a package variable, which *is* accessible.

Comment: Definitely going to try this - I think It'll help in future debugging similar issues:
`† Print out the main's symbol table, %main:: (using Data::Dumper for example)`

Comment: @Daklean Yeah, that is fun -- and informative -- to look at.  Messy though :).   Let me know if more/better info is needed here or there.  I will edit a little anyway

Answer (score 4):

[zdim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319092/1990570) gives a very good explanation of how package variables work and can be used. I don't think it directly answers the question of when they fall out of scope though.

Succinctly:

- Package variables are global static variables, just namespaced so the "global" aspect isn't as terrible.
- As with any static variable, **they are in scope for the entire execution of the program**.

You also asked:

> In my understanding of other more object oriented languages you would need to declare a new object instance, maybe with its own constructor/initialization functions to use "package" variables. That doesn't seem to be the case here with Perl.

Package variables are fairly unrelated to object-oriented programming in Perl. They are not used for storing instance data. (Except sometimes in the case of inside-out objects, though that's more of an advanced topic.)

Comment: so if i understand correctly, once you create an `our` variable, and the code is loaded with a `require` statement, it exists until the program ends, available to any body of code, any package, so long as: I correctly scope call the variable with `PERSON::$name`
is that right?

Comment: @Daklean  "_correctly scope call_" -- it is their "fully qualified name" (or form), `$PERSON::name` (dollar at beginning), for the namespace (package) `PERSON`.  Yes they are available everywhere (that's what my answer is all about).

Comment: @Daklean  "_so long as: I correctly scope call the variable with `PERSON::$name`_ -- if they are "_exported_" from the package, and imported into the calling code, then you can also use that name, as well.  And everywhere within the namespace into which they are imported.  (It's discussed briefly in my answer.)

Comment: @zdim yes I knew about the import functionality, but I'm not really trying to get this thing shared, I'm actually trying to get it instanced between calls. I think the appropriate thing would be to not try and make the existing code work, but to remove any unnecessary 'our' use, and just pass parameters around.

Comment: @Daklean "_but to remove any unnecessary 'our' use, and just pass parameters around_"  -- oh yes; better use the opportunity to improve the code!  But if you are dealing with classes then it's easy, just make objects in each scope where they are needed.  It'd be helpful if you could clarify what you have.

Comment: @Daklean, even *before* doing `require PERSON`, the `$PERSON::name` variable would *already* be available to code outside the module. You can set package variables before a module is loaded. (Though the module might then set the variables to some default values when it gets loaded, overwriting what you set before.)

Comment: @zdim it's hard to give concrete examples because the code base is so large, even to just require/load a file is handled with its own custom functions. which is why in my first example the file name doesn't match the package name. I guess for our implementation that's not required

Comment: @tobyink that actually hurts my brain to think about. but I suppose it makes sense given that they are indeed just global variables and not actually tied to their package in any way other than the pre:: name

Comment: @Daklean  "_it's hard to give concrete examples_" -- well, for one: is the package a class or not?  As you wish of course, but if there are questions of design (rewrite? if yes how? if not how to use? etc) then you could post such a question here but then you'd surely need a specific example.